# creating the appending text effect with javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const alphabets = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

const handleClick = async () => {
  let inputVal = document.getElementById('textInput').value.toLowerCase().split('')

  if (inputVal.length <= 0) return alert('Please Type something!')

  for (val in inputVal) {
    if (alphabets.includes(inputVal[val]) === false) return alert('Use only letters and space')
  }

  let inLen = inputVal.length
  let echTxt = 0
  let runningWordsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('runningWords')[0]

  do {
    console.log(echTxt)
    for (let letter = 0; letter <= alphabets.length; letter++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (alphabets[letter] === undefined) return
        runningWordsDiv.innerHTML = alphabets[letter].toUpperCase()
      }, 200 * letter);
    }
    echTxt++
  }
  while (echTxt < inLen)
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container .inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .inputs input {
  width: 30em;
  height: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: 0.25em solid transparent;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.container .inputs input:hover,
.container .inputs input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0.25em solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
}

.container .inputs button {
  width: 7em;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
  background-color: #333;
  color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .inputs button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
  color: #333;
}

.container .runningWords {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 20%;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="runningWords"></div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <input type="text" name="text" id="textInput" value="test" placeholder="Enter String...">
      <button onclick="handleClick()">Go...</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to create a text effect, where at first when we type something on input field and click on go button, whatever we type should be shown in the `runningWords` div, but with a effect like, if we type something as `test` then it should first append the `alphabets` when the first letter of typed word `t` matches the word in `alphabets`, then it should stop on that and then move to next append and the next word of types word is `e`, so the `alphabets` loop stop at `e` and move to next word of typed word. This the most i tried, but when i run the `console.log(echTxt)` it runs upto the types word length in an instant and then only it starts appending to the `runningWords` div. Please help me somebody.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to achieve something like this? Check inline comments:

```js
// Alphabet
const alphabets = [
  ' ',
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
  'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
  'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
  'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];

// Timeout function
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Handle click
const handleClick = async () => {
  // Loop visualization function
  const innerWithFx = async (letter, pre) => {
    // Loop alphabets
    for(const l of alphabets) {
      // Put letter
      runningWordsDiv.innerHTML = pre + l.toUpperCase();
      // If letters match
      if(l == letter) return l;
      // Sleep for timeout
      await timeout(100);
    }
  };
  // Target field
  const runningWordsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('runningWords')[0];
  // Read input string and split in to the array
  const inpArr = (document.getElementById('textInput').value).toLowerCase().split('');
  // Loop input array and run fx for each letter
  for(const letter of inpArr) {
    // Search for letter with fx
    const foundLetter = await innerWithFx(letter, runningWordsDiv.textContent);
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container .inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .inputs input {
  width: 30em;
  height: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: 0.25em solid transparent;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.container .inputs input:hover,
.container .inputs input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0.25em solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
}

.container .inputs button {
  position: relative;
  width: 7em;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 140, 255);
  background-color: #333;
  color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .inputs button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
  color: #333;
}

.runningWords {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 20%;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inputs">
      <div class="runningWords"></div>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="textInput" value="test" placeholder="Enter String...">
      <button onclick="handleClick()">Go...</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes its the one, thanks